# dojo datagrid set unsorted column icon

Tags: datagrid, dojo

i know dojo datagrid columns come sortable by default, however, initially there is no icon when the data is unsorted (there is a small triangle upward and downward for ascending and descending orders respectively). How can i add an icon when the data is unsorted?

thanks

Comment: When the data is unsorted, then what is the use of showing the arrow? The data of `dgrid` can have three states (by setting `hasNeutralSort` to true) : ascending, descending and unsorted. Arrow is shown for first two states and for unsorted there is no arrow.

Comment: @Himanshu not an arrow, another icon, something that conveys the idea of disarray. The user just asked for it.

Comment: If you just want to show that the data in `dgrid` is unsorted then you can add a node in the header of the grid. And the node will contain the icon that signifies that the grid is unsorted. But in this case, there will be a problem if the columns are `sortable`. Then you would have to see when the user is sorting and then remove the node that was inserted for unsorted data. It is easy, but you will have to look into code of grid.